# Using variables instead of values

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem with my existing code.

This code works fine,

```
Public Function jewel_intrate_new(ByVal duration As Integer) As String
    Select Case duration
        Case 0 : max2 = "0%"
        Case 1 To 33 : max2 = "3.5%"
        Case 34 To 63 : max2 = "9%"
        Case 64 To 93 : max2 = "14.5%"
        Case 94 To 123 : max2 = "20%"
        Case 124 To 153 : max2 = "25.5%"
        Case 154 To 183 : max2 = "31%"
        Case 184 To 213 : max2 = "36.5%"
        Case 214 To 243 : max2 = "42%"
        Case 244 To 273 : max2 = "47.5%"
        Case 274 To 303 : max2 = "53%"
        Case 304 To 333 : max2 = "58.5%"
        Case 334 To 363 : max2 = "64%"
        Case 364 To 393 : max2 = "69.5%"
        Case 394 To 423 : max2 = "75%"
        Case 424 To 453 : max2 = "80.5%"
        Case 454 To 483 : max2 = "86%"
        Case 484 To 513 : max2 = "91.5%"
        Case 514 To 543 : max2 = "97%"
        Case 544 To 573 : max2 = "102.5%"
        Case 574 To 603 : max2 = "108%"
        Case 604 To 633 : max2 = "113.5%"
        Case 634 To 663 : max2 = "119%"
        Case 664 To 693 : max2 = "124.5%"
    End Select
    Return max2
End Function
```

All i want is to make my app as editable the values so i update the code as follows:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As Double = 3.5 * 100, z As Integer, duration As Integer = TextBox1.Text
    Dim jj As Double = 3.5
    Select Case duration
        Case 0
            jj = 0
        Case 1 To 33
            jj = 3.5
        Case 34 To 9999

            z = (duration / 30)
            For i As Integer = 1 To z
                jj += 3.5 + 2 'this will be editable in database.
            Next

    End Select
    Label1.Text = jj & "%"
End Sub
```

But they don't have the same output.
Is there anyway to make my function simpler and shorter?

monthly interest is `3.5%`

penalty interest is `2%` after 33 days

monthly is `30` days plus `3` days grace period

Comment: If the code is already working, try asking on [codereview.se]. Be sure to read their help center before asking. (in this case the second snippet is not working so I'm not sure...)

Comment: @user202729, that code works fine but the interest rate is not editable.. :(

Comment: Ask only one question in each question please. How is "the interest rate is not editable" related to your question?

Comment: What does "All i want is to make my app as editable the values so i update the code as follows" mean?

Comment: on the first function interest rate is fixed base on the duration, sorry for being not clear. the `max2` is fixed as it is declared. on the second, on button1.click the interest rate (`3.5`) and the penalty interest (`2`) can be editable i'll just  update the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These results should match your Select Case but you can pass in any interest rate or penalty interest. Import System.Math. Test against your Select Case.

```
Private Function Calculate(ByVal Duration As Integer, InterestRate As Double, PenaltyRate As Double) As Double
        Dim Rate As Double
        Dim Multiplier As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling((Duration - 3) / 30))
        Rate = Multiplier * InterestRate + PenaltyRate * (Multiplier - 1)
        Return Rate
End Function
```

Comment: this is what i'm what looking for. thank you so much @Mary